# How can I focus to current web page from search or address bar on Firefox 60.2.0

Tags: firefox

When I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is similar quickly keyboard shortcuts to focus to current web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From
[Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly):

> Move to Next Frame    <kbd>F6</kbd>
>   Move to Previous Frame    <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>